# SQL Server stored procedure - share temp tables

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure that has quite complex logic at the begining and it saves some data to temp tables.

Then some select statements are performed on those temp tables and stored procedure generates few result sets.

Now I would like to split it into few stored procedures so that each stored procedure generates only one result set, but the problem is that I don't want to duplicate code and still use temp tables from core part of main stored procedure.

Is it possible to share temp tables between stored procedures executions?

Comment: Although there may be more recent options, have you seen [Using a temp table between stored procedures in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6018521/1115360)?

Comment: [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](https://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a global temp table, you can see and edit the context over different Stored Procedures.
Keep in mind that when a Stored Proc is being executed on the same time, it uses the same table. So perhaps you need an identifier (e.g. the @@SPID).

See link for example.
[Global temptable](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6035/local-vs-global-sql-server-temporary-tables/)